# Nested arrays: How to append a new datapoint?

Tags: python, rethinkdb

Sorry for the confusing title but not sure how to shortly explain this.

I have a database with Arrays within Arrays, example:

```
r.db('test').table('Example').insert({'id':'Object1',
    'History':{'16-07-2018':{'Price':25,'Volume':200}}
     })
```

What I want to do is to add a new object. If the ID doesn't exists, create it. If it already exists then add new dates to the history (This is my first question, how to do this? Using insert and then `conflict=update` ?), something like:

```
Insert Object1 -> History -> 17-07-2018 -> {Price:40,Volume:150}
```

So the result would be

```
{
"History": {
"16-07-2018": {
"Volume": 200,
"Price": 25
} ,
"17-07-2018": {
"Volume": 150,
"Price": 40
}
} ,
"id":  "Object1"
}
```

Summarizing:

1) How to tell Rethink to insert a new line if it doesn't exist, and update it if it actually exist based on id?

2) How to append to arrays within db?

Thanks!

Comment: It's object of objects, not array...

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the title is misleading since you're working with objects and not arrays.

For objects, the `conflict: 'update'` option does everything required (creates/updates the object, updates/"appends" the history).

For (real) arrays, one can use the `conflict` option as well, since it can take a function as a value:

```
r.db....insert({
  id: 'Object1',
  history: [{
    date: '2018-01-01',
    price: 40,
    volume: 250
  }]
}, {
  conflict: function(id, oldDoc, newDoc) {
    return r.branch(
      newDoc('history').count().ne(1),
      r.error("When updating, only one history item is allowed"),
      r.do(function() {
        var offsets = oldDoc('history').offsetsOf(function(item) {
          return item('date').eq(newDoc('history').nth(0)('date'));
        });
        return oldDoc.merge({
          history: r.branch(
            offsets.isEmpty(),
            oldDoc('history').append(newDoc('history').nth(0)),
            oldDoc('history').changeAt(offsets.nth(0), newDoc('history').nth(0))
          )
        });
      })
    );
}})
```